# arduino RX not working

Tags: interface, arduino, serial-port, gsm

I am trying to read an SMS message from a GSM modem .

My arduino TX and RX are connected to a MAX232 IC and from the IC another 2 wires goes to the RS232 cable of the Modem.

I am capable of sending a string to the modem. I even sent an SMS from the arduino.  and I also see the TX led flashing when sending the strings

When I try to read the responses from the modem I get nothing not even the RX led blinking even when I type something in the serial monitor nothing happens

When I disconnect the RX pin of the arduino that goes to the MAX232 it works . When i send something through the serial port it works, the RX led blinks and the prints me back the string as supposed

any ideas are appreceated

Thanks

Comment: Your modem maybe use additional pins(CTS,DTR, etc). Can't communicate if haven't any one message end delimeter(So message end is hardware pin.).

Comment: I'm pretty much scared about that `another 2 wires` sentence... You DID connect the ground wire, didn't you?